# Contruct a DateTime with Custom Hours and Minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I need to construct a DateTime object with the date coming from a calendar and the hours/mins/am-pm coming from three drop down lists.

The DateTime is being inserted into a DB as a regular DateTime SQL Server DB type. I'll use something like string dt = String.Format("{0:g}", DateTime.Now); to parse it when grabbing it from the DB.

I just need to find an elegant way to construct the DateTime object for the DB insertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the standard `DateTime` constructor overload detailed [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130.aspx).

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
```

Where you grab the `year`, `month`, `day` from your calendar, and the `hour`, `minute`, `second` values from parsed drop down values.

Comment: Great... forgot that I could just zero out the seconds in the constructor. Will mark as answer in a few :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of built-in constructor overloads for `DateTime()` that already do everything you need and will build a `DateTime` based on various inputs.